# ¿Cómo obtengo algunos datos de un producto en Woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Buen día, estoy intentando hacer un plugin que solo muestre los datos que necesito de un producto (SKU, NOMBRE y PRECIO). Y encontré este código en la referencia de Woocomerce, me ha funcionado bien, pero no sé como extraer los datos puntuales de cada uno.

```
    <?php
    /* Variables a definir*/
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
        );

    /* Query*/
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );


    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta las funciones que te traigan los datos que mencionas:

```
echo $product->get_name();
echo $product->get_sku();
echo $product->get_price();
```

acuerdate de invocar

```
global $product;
```

al principio de tu php si no estás dentro del loop,
ya que estos códigos puedes ponerlos en templates.